# Prove that $\int_0^{a}{\int_x^a{t^{-1}f(t)dt}} = \int_0^a{f(x)dx}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

I got stuck on this problem from Real Analysis by Folland. Can anybody give me any hints on how to solve this?

> If $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $(0, a)$ and
>   $$
> g(x) = \int_x^a{t^{-1}f(t)dt}
> $$
>   then $g$ is integrable on $(0, a)$ and
>
> $$
> \int_0^a{g(x)dx} = \int_0^a{f(x)dx}
> $$

Comment: Write $\int_x^a t^{-1} f(t)\,dt$ as $\int_0^a \chi_{[x,a]}(t) t^{-1}f(t)\,dt.$ Note that you will have to change the interval for $\chi$ when you interchange the integrals from $[x,a]$ to some interval involving $t$.

Comment: You have to show that $\|g\|_1<\infty$, and that can be done by invoking Fubini's Theorem.  You should be able to prove that $\|g\|_1\leq\|f\|_1<\infty$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: I'm not sure that I guess your suggestion right: Firstly, we have $t^{-1} \chi_{[x, a]}(t) f(t) \in L^+$, therefore we can apply the Fubini theorem, and the interval you mentioned will become $[0, t]$ for $x$, therefore $\int_0^a{g(x)}dx = \int_0^a(\int_0^t{t^{-1}f(t)dx})dt = \int_0^a{f(t)dt}$. Is there any mistake, you think?

Comment: Why should $f$ be in $L^+$?

Comment: @Batominovski: In the condition for Fubini-Tonelli theorem, $f$ must be in $L^+$ or $L^1$. For sure showing it in $L^+$ is easier here, right?

Comment: Then, you are only proving your result for $f\in L^+$.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I got confused between the domain and range of the function $f$. Hm, seem like I have to show that the function below integral is Lebesgue integrable, too. Let me think about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h(t)=\frac{f(t)}{t}1_{[y,a]}(t),\:0<y<a$. Since $0<1/t<M$ on $[y,a]$, $h(t)$ is integrable, i.e
$$
\int_y^{a}{\int_x^a|h(t)|dt}\:dx<aM\int_x^a|f(t)|dt<\infty
$$
By Fubini's theorem
\begin{align}
\int_y^{a}{\int_x^ah(t)dt}\:dx &=\int_y^a \frac{f(t)}{t}\int_y^{t}dx\:dt
\\
&=\int_y^a (t-y)\frac{f(t)}{t}\:dt
\\
&=\int_y^a f(t)\:dt-\int_y^a \frac{y}{t}f(t)\:dt\tag{1}
\end{align}
Note that bound for $x$ changes to [$y,t$] because $t$ is from $x$ to $a$.
Since for any $y\in(0,t],\:y<t$
$$
\frac{y}{t}f(t)<f(t) 
$$
Thus $\frac{y}{t}f(t)$ is integrable for $f$ is integrable. Also for any $t\in(0,a]$, there is
$$
\lim_{y\to0+}\frac{y}{t}f(t)=0\tag{2}
$$
By Dominated convergence theorem, (1) and (2)
$$
\lim_{y\to0+}\int_y^{a}{\int_x^ah(t)dt}\:dx =\int_0^a f(t)\:dt-\lim_{y\to0+}\int_y^a \frac{y}{t}f(t)\:dt=\int_0^a f(t)\:dt
$$

Comment: What you did was showing that, **if** $g$ is integrable, then $\int_0^a\,g(x)\,\text{d}x=\int_0^a\,f(x)\,\text{d}x$.  You haven't shown that $g$ is integrable.  But that part is best left for the OP.  I gave him/her a hint already.

Comment: There's some point I don't understand here. Sorry for my stupidity:
1) How can you state that $h(t)$ is bounded if $f(t)$ does not need to be bounded? Or integrable function need to be bounded?
2) Even when h(t) bounded, how can you apply Fubini theorem for it. The condition for Fubini theorem is non-negative measurable or Lebesgue integral
Please explain for me. Thanks so much

Comment: Oh, seem like the expression is so long that it overflows other part in the page. But let me try to read

Comment: Hm, seem like you change the proving by using limit, right. I think your old approach is better, just need to prove that function under integral is integrable by using Fubini for its absolute value. I think it is clearer somehow. But thanks anyway, @hermes.